# angular ckeditor extra plugins giving error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg, mathjax

I am trying to use the following angular ckeditor extension -

```
https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor
```

UPDATE: 
Already injected 'ckeditor' in the app modules

I am inserting the following directive into my partial html -

```
<div ckeditor="data_options" ng-model="note.note_data" ready="onReady()"></div>
```

and adding the following configuration options to the controller -

```
$scope.data_options = {
            lang: 'en',
            allowedContent: true,
            entities: false,
            extraPlugins: ['mathjax'],
            mathJaxClass: 'm-equation',
            mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML'
        };
```

But I am getting the following error in the browser -

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.replace is not a functionA @ ckeditor.js:249(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:248(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:475(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:236e @ ckeditor.js:231A @ ckeditor.js:231r @ ckeditor.js:231(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:232
```

Am I making any other error or this might be a bug or something ? 
Are there any alternatives to this for getting a angular wysiwyg editor with mathjax(tex/latex) support

Comment: Did you inject "ckeditor" to module dependency ?

Comment: yes. it works without the extraplugins, mathjaxlib, class config options

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

extraPlugins has to be a string, not an array, like this:

```
$scope.data_options = {
            lang: 'en',
            allowedContent: true,
            entities: false,
            extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
            mathJaxClass: 'm-equation',
            mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML'
        };
```

To use multiple extra plugins, you just use comma-separation:

```
extraPlugins: 'plugin1,plugin2,plugin2'
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.